# непонятки с css columns

Tags: css, css3

Добра вам, люди. Такая ситуация, имеем следующий код:

```
<section id="section-1" class="content-current">
<div class="mediabox"></div>
<div class="mediabox"></div>
<div class="mediabox"></div>
<div class="mediabox"></div>
<div class="mediabox"></div>
</section>
```

и соответствующий css:

```
section {
-webkit-columns: 250px;
-moz-columns: 250px;
columns: 250px;
display: none;
max-width: 1230px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.mediabox {
min-width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Проблема - предпоследние два дива не хотят выстраиваться в отдельные колонки при любой заданной ширине, вот [пациент](http://bzphoto.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE/). Помогите советом да напутствием добрым.

Comment: Поставьте `.mediabox { display: block; }`.

Comment: @cyadvert в этом случае блоки разрываются, заголовок может остаться в предыдущей колонке, а изображение уехать в следующую

Comment: да, понятно... но это зависит от объемов содержимого Ваших `.mediabox` Добавите в любой что-то - все опять переедет.
Вам либо надо уходить от колонок, либо найти способ "прилепить" колонку к первому содержимому...

Answer (score 2):

Если верно понял задачу:

```
.content section.content-current {
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* И другие префиксы*/
column-count: 3;
}
.mediabox {    
    width: 100%; /*Здесь браузер сам посчитает нужную ширину, ее не нужно задавать*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0 1em;    
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, нет. Auto нужно, инчае никакой адаптивности, а ширина 250px. Пришлось переписать css с медиазапросами, но причину установить все же нужно, она никуда не делась